# PTIJ: Why would the tzaddikim be barred from the carrying bars?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

King David tells us in [Tehillim (55:23)](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.55.23?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) לא יתן לעולם מוט לצדיק, [Hashem] will never give a carrying bar/pole to a tzaddik.

Now, granted, such poles have sometimes been used for nefarious purposes, like when the Spies used them to carry back gigantic fruit from Eretz Yisrael in order to slander the Land ([Bamidbar 13:23 and Rashi there](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.13.23?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he)). But on the other hand, a מוט was used to carry the Menorah and other sacred vessels of the Mishkan ([Bamidbar 4:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.4.10?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), 12), and even the carrying poles of the Aron are sometimes called מוטות ([I Divrei Hayamim 15:15](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.15.15?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), and [Rashi to Shemos 25:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.25.13?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he)).

So why are such bars barred to the tzaddikim?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1):

Koheles 7:20:

> כִּ֣י אָדָ֔ם אֵ֥ין צַדִּ֖יק בָּאָ֑רֶץ אֲשֶׁ֥ר יַעֲשֶׂה־טּ֖וֹב וְלֹ֥א יֶחֱטָֽא׃
>
> There is no Tzadik in the world which will do good but not sin.

If the ט-ו of טוב is combined with the Gematria of the subsequent four letters in the verse ב-ו-ל-א that equals 39, [which is the same as 40](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90033/gematriot-that-differ-by-1), the numerical equivelant of מ, leaving us with טומ. Backwards we have:

> There is no Tzadik in the world which will do MOT.

Thus, Tzadikim are not granted poles, because they simply are not geared for that type of life.